# Javascript 6 character and space check

Tags: javascript

I want to find if the userinput has 6 characters and if it has a space in position 4 or i guess 5 if it stars counting from zero. Im new to java script and think I'm over thinking it please help!

Comment: How did you tried to implement it, share some code!

Answer (score 2):

However your question is not much clear to me at 'or i guess 5 if it starts counting from zero' but as much as I understood from your question the answer is as follow:

```
// get the user input through it id or whatever 
// CSS selector you are using
var userInput = document.querySelector('#user_input');

// on whatever event you are doing this check
// insert the following code to its handler
if (userInput.value.length === 6 && userInput.value[3] === " ") {
  // your check is true here and do whatever you want
  // return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (userinput.length === 6 && userinput.charAt(4) === " ") {
    // This is where your code goes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the function to check the user input has 6 characters or not:

```
function validateUserInput(inputNo) {

    if (inputNo.length == 6) {
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Following is the function to validate 4th character is space or not:

```
function checkFourthCharacterAsSpace(inputNo) {

    var value = inputNo.charAt(3);  // index starts from 0
    if(value == ' ') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function takes the input, then it verifies that it's a string obj so you can properly handle it and performs the check you need.

```
function _check_me( _input_obj )
{
    if ( typeof _input_obj  == "string" || _input_obj  instanceof String )
    {
         return ( _input_obj.length == 6 && ( _input_obj.charAt(4) == " " || _input_obj.charAt(5) == " " ) ) ? 1 : 0 ;

    }
    else return 0 ;
}
```

Hence you can use it, as exampled below:

```
var _obj1 = "abcdef"; // returns false
var _obj2 = "abcd f"; // returns true
var _obj3 = "abc ef"; // returns true

document.write( _obj1 + " : " + _check_me( _obj1 ) + "<br>" ) ;
document.write( _obj2 + " : " + _check_me( _obj2 ) + "<br>" ) ;
document.write( _obj3 + " : " + _check_me( _obj3 ) + "<br>" ) ;
```

Hope it helps and happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work. I used "regular expressions" to test for your requirements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test for pattern</title>
<script>

function testInput(){
   // get text input element
   var inputBox = document.getElementById("txtInput");
   var backgroundColor = "red";
   //check if the inputted text matches the regex.
   if(inputBox.value.match(/^\w{3}\s\w{2}$/g)){
       backgroundColor = "green";
       //.. or add whatever has to be done ...
   }
   inputBox.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="txtInput" type="text" onkeyup="testInput()">
</body>
</html>
```

Working example : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StevenLangeraert/q7t4e72L/1/)